# How to get user defined field in message file INET

Tags: c++, omnet++, inet

I would to send user data, so i added a field in the message file :

```
class MpeiMacHeader extends MacHeaderBase
{
    MPEIMacType   type;
    uint32_t data;
}
```

This is what the received message looks like :
[msg fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrcQh.png)

I didn't success to get the field `data` in my code. I tried several expressions, i could only get : [msg fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0anK.png)

But when I try to compile with `msg->content` in my code :

```
no member named 'content' in 'omnetpp::cMessage'
```

How to get this field in my code ? There is a `getData()` in generated files, but i didn't find how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to get the data in `handleSelfMessage()`, I found a solution using `handleLowerPacket()` :

```
void MpeiMac::handleLowerPacket(Packet *packet)
{
    if (packet->hasBitError())
    {
        ...
    }
    else
    {
        const auto& hdr = packet->peekAtFront<MpeiMacHeader>();
        packet->setKind(hdr->getType());

        if( hostID == 0 )
            data = hdr->getData();
        // simply pass the massage as self message, to be processed by the FSM.
        handleSelfMessage(packet);
    }
}
```

Maybe this section can explain : [inet_developers-guide](https://inet.omnetpp.org/docs/developers-guide/ch-packets.html#emulation-support) :